# Философия Java Брюс Эккель где скачать его библиотеку?

Tags: java

Подскажите, где скачать его библиотеку net.mindview.util для решения задач по книге.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск библиотек, книг, плагинов - оффтопик на сайте.

Comment: [Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) являются оффтопиком.

Answer (score 6):

Вы не поверите! Автор выложил код к книге на GitHub - https://github.com/BruceEckel/TIJ4-code

Comment: А он молодой, оказывается, а я думал что он дедушка вроде Столлмана :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe у них всего 4 года разницы, Столлмана бородища старит :)

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в таких случаях следует загуглить: `net.mindview.util downland java`.
Я это сделал и нашел по второй ссылке: [здесь](http://prog3.com/sbdm/download/detail/zhaoqingkaitt/8538205)